# How can I know,whether the tools that the user used is table or matrix in RDLC?

Tags: c#

I want to know that the tools that were used in rdlc is table or matrix.

How can I know?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you need the info on tools that are used to creat rdlc files? or any tutorials to learn rdlc development. In both cases, the question is off topic; you can improve your question by adding what you have done so far or any specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the control, i think if you can add groups in column then that is a matrix if not then it is a table.